# How can I maintain responsive sizing and positioning better with CSS?

Tags: html, css

i am working on chat application i want to make the button to be responsive for all the screen width below i added the code for the reference
Try shrinking the page width-wise and you'll see my issue. How can I keep the button size and position as close to the same as desktop as possible when resizing the screen? I'm stumped.

Pen: https://codepen.io/trjwaugh/pen/QWvypQJ

```css
//FONTS
$heading-font: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
$main-font: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

//COLORS
$btn-blue: #35A7FF;

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#header__chat {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 40%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 50vw;
    max-width: 1000px;
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 111, 0.2) 0px 7px 29px 0px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    animation:  5s;
  }

  #header__btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 72%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 6vw;
    display: flex;
    padding: 30px;
    box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 111, 0.2) 0px 7px 29px 0px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background-color: $btn-blue;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    h2{
      font-size: 2vw;
      padding: 10px;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
  }

h1 {
    font-size: 5vw;
    font-family: $heading-font;
  }

h2 {
    font-size: 2vw;
    font-family: $heading-font;
}


.typing {
    width: 12ch;
    animation: typing 2s steps(22), blink .5s step-end infinite alternate;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: 3px solid;
  }
  
@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
}
      
@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    border-color: transparent
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <!--- Required Meta Tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="Hello, I'm Tim. A Frontend Web Developer, always curious, learning and growing my skills in web design, data, analytics and software in general.">
    <!--- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    
    <head>
        <style>@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header__chat">
            <h1 class="typing">Text Goes Here.</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="header__btn">
            <h2>Send</h2>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vanilla-tilt/1.7.0/vanilla-tilt.min.js" integrity="sha512-SttpKhJqONuBVxbRcuH0wezjuX+BoFoli0yPsnrAADcHsQMW8rkR84ItFHGIkPvhnlRnE2FaifDOUw+EltbuHg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use css media queries for responsive deisgns. Please refer [https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score -1):

By using media queries adjust the `padding` , `width`, height of button according to screen size

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #header__btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 75%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #35A7FF;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
}
```

please refer this [w3 schools media queires](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to clearly understand what is media queries

here i attached the reference image on changing css

[image: reference image]